# Temporarily save git changes

Tags: git, repository

I am having trouble with `GIT` repository, I want

1. if I switch to another branch **Production**, `changes` in my current branch **Development** get saved some where(my be stashed)
2. Switched branch **Production** remain intact of my previous changes.
3. and when I switch back to previous **Development** branch I retrieve back my changes (stash pop).

I thought about stashing my changes but it is not working as per my expectations (or I might have understood it all wring).

if I had changes in 3 files before branch switch, I still can see 3 changes in checked-out branch. That is not what I am expecting.

Here are the steps I performed

```
D:\my-code>git status
On branch development
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/development'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        java/com/web1/cc/Category.java
        java/com/web1/cc/Product.java
        java/com/web1/cc/Relationship.java

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I though if I git-stash these files will be stashed but not happening.

```
D:\my-code>git stash
No local changes to save
```

**Please** note these 3 files are actually new files.

however if I again issue `git status` it show me 3 files changes.

I want to create build from Production branch and want to ignore these 3 files. (For now what I do is copy my src folder some where else and reset the changes, switch branch create build, switch back, merge changes that I save some where else).

I am hopeful I have explained my problem.

Comment: Make a new branch to save the tmp changes. A branch is easier and clearer to manipulate. You could leave it alone or delete it when it's no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason these files does not get stashed is that they are not under version control. You can try first adding them to version control by issuing command `git add .` and then `git stash`

Comment: `git add .` could you please explain bit more. I know its not staged, and I think its not committed(not sure though)?
after I perform task on other branch, how can I can retrieve these changes back(Coz I am not sure I will commit those changes are not).

Comment: @PHPAvenger `git add .` will add all modified and untracked files to the staging area, then you can `git stash` all them.